# How do I get the full local path of a file uploaded with $_FILES

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

I am uploaded a file through the file input.  If I print_r($_FILES), I can get several pieces of info, but it doesn't give me the full LOCAL path of the file (the path on my computer, not the server).  How do I get this?

I need this to use the FTP library in CodeIgniter.  Documentation is [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/ftp.html) on how to use it to upload a file.

As you can see, it requires the full local path, although I'm not sure why.

Comment: I want to use the CI FTP class rather than file upload because it is a more robust class and provides the tools I need to build a file manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As file upload path is a variable which changes from server to server, I would suggest you to use `move_uploaded_file()` function:

```
$target = "uploads/myfile.something";
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
    // do something
}
```

that way it will always work no matter what the path is even if it changes. The `target` can be anything you wish, it's relative to the current folder where script is being executed.

Comment: No, what I need is the path of the file on the COMPUTER the user is using to upload the file, not on the SERVER.

Comment: It looks like CI won't upload a file from a local computer.  It will only move files on the server, from what I can tell.  But the jury is not quite in yet.

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. It is impossible to read path, as it would be a great security issue, that's why it is a security restriction in JS. However, it was possible until IE8 and FF3, I don't think that would be what you need.

Comment: *** with PHP it was, is and will be impossible, as with any other server-side language as when the file is passed to the server using multipart form data, no information about the path is sent.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.

```
public function upload($file, $folder) {
  $this->CI->ftp->upload($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], '/public_html/rest/of/path/' . $_FILES['file']['name'], 'ascii', 0775);
 }
```

The file is being uploaded, so you can access it with `$FILES['file']['tmp_name']`.  This is from within a class, so that's why I'm using `$this->CI`.  Otherwise, I would just use `$this`.